# How to create new JSONAction in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I would like to create a new JSON Action, similar to GetLayoutsAction but returning list of defined forms. How can I do this?

Comment: What's " list of defined forms" ?

Comment: In Liferay you can create forms with specific fields. I would like to get a list of all this forms. That's not the problem - there'a API for that. The question is, how can I create portlet, which will return JSON with that data.

Comment: Forms are represented by the DDLRecordSet entities (and a bunch of related entities). You can get the list of record sets from a Liferay site via the Axis API. Check http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws?contextName=ddl&signature=%2Fddl.ddlrecordset%2Fget-record-sets-1-groupIds Once you check, let us know if this list can be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution in my case.